# Application.Current.Properties deserialization crash

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xamarin.forms

I store an object to Properties (if its not already stored):

```
if (!Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("user"))
{
    Application.Current.Properties.Add("user", user);
}
```

It has stored the first object. Than I set it to null. When I try to check `ContainsKey` again now it raises an exception:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'
SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 264. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value' contains data of the 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Layouts.Models:User' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'User' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Should I delete... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check docs at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/ :

> Note: the Properties dictionary can only serialize primitive types for
>   storage. Attempting to store other types (such as List can
>   fail silently.

In topic "Persistence" it's written: "The Properties dictionary is saved to the device automatically. " Therefore you get exception immediately.

Workaround is to serialize/deserialize your User object manually. Here is an example using JSON serialization: https://codemilltech.com/persist-whatever-you-want-with-xamarin-forms/